# SSRS report Slow in Reporting Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a report SSRS deployed in reporting service, during the execution it is very slow on the other hand that if I run in visual studio (SSDT) it works fast (query return 200 000 lines)

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your report server could have resource issues. However from my experience it is more likely that the difference is due to the CRM user accounts executing the reports from the two different environments. There is significant overhead involved with accessing the filtered views with a non-admin account because of the underlying security mechanisms built into those views. If you are using filtered views, and running the reports in Visual Studio using an account with System Administrator permissions, while the reporting services account is not a System Administrator then that could explain the behavior.

Are you using filtered views? Can you post your query code?

**Update:**
Since you think you are not using filtered views then I would try a few different things:
- Verify that the version of the report being rendered on the report server is the same version that you are working on in VS (e.g. make a small change and verify it carries across)
- Make sure your query is as efficient as possible. I don't see anything obviously wrong with the partial code you posted but that doesn't mean much since we can't see how your temp tables are being generated.
- Review indexes on the tables involved in the report, and add any missing indexes

Comment: i'm not using filteredView , 
my query contains several processes and temporary tables and a select query at the end
for example when I take top 1000 of this last request the display is done ,but not for the entire query result

Comment: SELECT *
FROM ##Temps_EtatJournalComptable  Tcum  WITH (NOLOCK)
       inner join BusinessUnit Expclt     WITH (NOLOCK)  on Tcum.Exp_Clientid = Expclt.fan_CodeDivision
       inner join #JOURNAL_COMPT j        WITH (NOLOCK) on Tcum.Codedujournal=j.gs2e_Codedujournal
       left join  #TRANSACTIONS_NMPF   nm WITH (NOLOCK) on nm.gs2e_mouvementcomptableId=Tcum.gs2e_mouvementcomptableId
       left join  #TRANSACTIONS_arret arr WITH (NOLOCK) on arr.gs2e_mouvementcomptableId=Tcum.gs2e_mouvementcomptableId

Comment: this is last part of query because it's so long

Comment: You should post the code within your original post so that you can format it and include larger code blocks. I have updated my answer with some additional suggestions.